# how can i disable a text field on radio click, enable text on another radio click and clear the three using a link

Tags: php

So I have a php form that I am creating and it has hundreds of fields.
If a radio input repair is selected I want to enter text in the text field.
If radio monitor is selected I want to disable the input text field.
If clear is clicked, I want to clear only the two radio buttons and disable the input text field

```
<h5>FL7 - </h5>
<div class="input-group m-b-15">
    <div class="input-group m-b-15">
        <span class="js-clear">Clear</span>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-danger form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="val-55" value="r" id="repair_55">
        <label for="repair_55">Monitor</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-warning form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="val-55" value="m" id="monitor_55">
        <label for="monitor_55">Repair</label>
        <input name="comment_55" type="text" class="form-control" id="comment_55" >
    </div>
</div>
<h5>FL8 - </h5>
<div class="input-group m-b-15">
    <div class="input-group m-b-15">
        <span class="js-clear">Clear</span>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-danger form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="val-56" value="r" id="repair_56">
        <label for="repair_56">Monitor</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-warning form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="val-56" value="m" id="monitor_56">
        <label for="monitor_56">Repair</label>
        <input name="comment_56" type="text" class="form-control" id="comment_56" >
    </div>
</div>
<h5>FL9 - </h5>
<div class="input-group m-b-15">
    <div class="input-group m-b-15">
        <span class="js-clear">Clear</span>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-danger form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="val-57" value="r" id="repair_57">
        <label for="repair_57">Monitor</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-warning form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="val-57" value="m" id="monitor_57">
        <label for="monitor_57">Repair</label>
        <input name="comment_57" type="text" class="form-control" id="comment_57" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you need is JavaScript/jQuery to do that, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript instead of using php. Php requires server-side access and can not be executed on the client side alone which would make it useless for manipulating a form. Check out how to do this below with the example

The text input and the radio button

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="radio" id="radio_button" />
```

The javascript part

```
$("#radioButton").click(function(){
    //disable the text field
    document.getElementById('username').setAttribute('disabled ', 'disabled');
});
```

That should be able to help you

Comment: ok, how do I set this up as a variable?
I have over 500 of these options and don't want to add this code for each item, lol

Comment: So am not sure of a way to set all of them once other than doing it one by one. Sorry!